# Massive fps drops when AVAudioPlayer ist triggered repeatedly (Sprite Kit)

Tags: sprite-kit, avaudioplayer, frame-rate

I am creating an iOS-Game in Sprite Kit in which you can fire a water gun. As long as the water gun is fired, a slash-sound is played. Since I implemented this feature, I have massive fps-problems when the sound effect ist triggered repeatedly with the touches-began-method.

Is there any possibility to fix that issue?

```
@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *splashSound;

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

    NSError *error3;
    NSURL *splashURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"splash" withExtension:@"caf"];
    self.splashSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:splashURL error:&error3];
    self.splashSound.numberOfLoops = 1;
    [self.splashSound prepareToPlay];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    startGamePlay = YES;
    if (self.waterCapacity != 0){
    waterSprayed = YES;
    [self.splashSound play]; // sound starts when screen is touched
    [self.currentWasser sprayWater];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.currentWasser removeActionForKey:@"water"];
    [self.splashSound pause]; // sound is paused when touches ended
    waterSprayed = NO;
}
```

Comment: Why is number of loops 1 when the sound effect is supposed to keep playing? If it's a long audio file you should change that to a small one (1-5 seconds) and simply loop it. PS: If you don't use the error object you can just pass in error:nil in the init method.

Comment: Has this been tested on a real device?  The simulator is terrible.

Comment: thank you for your reply. unfortunately this change does not make any difference. i think i will a UILongPressGestureRecognizer in order to play the sound file after 1 second after the screen is touched. i think i can prevent the low fps this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it with an UILongPressGestureRecognizer: works perfectly. So happy!

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(delayedSplashSound:)];
    longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.15;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:longGesture];
}

- (void)delayedSplashSound:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self.splashSound play];
    }else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        [self.splashSound pause];
        [self.currentWater removeActionForKey:@"water"];
        waterSprayed = NO;
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    startGamePlay = YES;
    if (self.waterCapacity != 0){
    waterSprayed = YES;
    [self.currentWater sprayWater];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.currentWater removeActionForKey:@"water"];
    waterSprayed = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another work-around for the frame-drops when using `AVAudioPlayer.play()` and `AVAudioPlayer.stop()` with an infinite loop. Instead of calling `play()` and `stop()`, just call `play()` once and set `yourPlayerInstance.volume=0.0` and `yourPlayerInstance.volume=1.0`. This solved the frame-glitches/-drops for me - perfect 60 fps instead of drops to ~40 fps.