# SpriteKit background music not looping forever

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm making a simple SpriteKit game with two scenes, and I want the background music to loop unconditionally through both scenes. Right now, I'm using

```
if soundIsPlaying == false {
   runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(backgroundMusicEffect), withKey: "backgroundMusic")
   soundIsPlaying = true
}
```

in my menu scene where `backgroundMusicEffect` is a global variable

```
let backgroundMusicEffect = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("content/divertimentoK131.mp3", waitForCompletion: true)
```

When I play my game, the music never loops. It always stops after one play. If I remove the if-else statement, the music plays over itself every time I reenter the menu.

Is there a better way to play background music? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38486792/1894067

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the way you are doing it,  after the first time looping, every iteration after is "complete" since the sound is finished.  You would need to create a new SKAction instance every time if you want to get this to loop.

This of course is a bad idea, since `playSoundFileNamed` is designed to only play a sound file once with as little over head as possible.

As @Alessandro Omano has commented,  use SKAudioNode to get sound playing in a loop.  This is my preferred way of doing in, but you limit yourself to >= iOS 9 users.

If you have to support iOS 8 users (At this point I would say why bother)  then you need to look into the AVFoundation sections of the libs to get audio going, or use OpenAL.

Comment: thank you, I've added using the SKAudioNode following @alessandro-ornano 's guide, but now the music crashes after one second of playing.. is there a way to avoid this? (it also failed to carry over from scene to scene)

Comment: if you want to carry over from scene to scene, you need to transfer the AudioNode over to the new scene.  As for the crashing,  would need more info,  I am not sure what @Alessandro Omano's guide does, so I can't help in that regard..